# Codecheck isn't letting me pass

Tags: java

Hey I have a code that gives off an error. Not sure why and how. But can anyone help me with this?

Error:

> /tmp/codecheck.rA4OvRYwJM/InterfaceTester.java:6: error: constructor
>   Sphere in class Sphere cannot be applied to given types;
>
> ```
>    GeometricSolid shape = new Sphere(10);
>                           ^   required: no arguments   found: int
> ```
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>
> /tmp/codecheck.rA4OvRYwJM/InterfaceTester.java:10: error: constructor
>
> Sphere in class Sphere cannot be applied to given types;
>
> ```
>    shape = new Sphere(1);
>            ^   required: no arguments   found: int
> ```
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 2 errors

This is my code and the link to codecheck http://www.codecheck.it/files/18040616263h5pl4lvxfmzj6u9w7xty4dfu

```
 /**
 * Write a description of class asdasdasd here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public interface GeometricSolid
{
    public double volume();

}

import java.util.*;
public class Sphere implements GeometricSolid
{
double radius;
    /**
     * Gets the volume of sphere
     * @return volume volume of sphere
     */
    public double volume()
    {
        double volume = 4.0 * Math.PI * Math.pow(this.radius, 3) / 3.0;
        return volume;
    }

    /**
     * Get radius of sphere
     * @return the radius of sphere
     */
    public double getRadius()
    {
        return radius;
    }
    /**
     * set radius for sphere
     * @param newRadius of a sphere
     */
    public void setRadius(int newRadius)
    {
        radius = newRadius;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beginner Java required no arguments error on constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266913/beginner-java-required-no-arguments-error-on-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an constructor to the `Sphere`class that takes the radius as argument and passes it to the variable.
For example:

```
public Sphere(double radius){
     this.radius = radius;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is very explicit about what the error is in this case.

> required: no arguments
>   found: int

The constructor (in your case the default no-argument constructor generated by Java automatically) does not take any arguments and you are trying to pass it an integer.

Because your sphere has a setter, you can instantiate the same `Sphere` like so:

```
Sphere shape = new Sphere();
shape.setRadius(1);
```

It's unusual that your setter takes an integer but the getter and the field use doubles. You should probably change that.